# How To get the values of object sorted with keys in distinct arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, object

Given an array of arrays, I want to get the averages of each subarray, and then output which subarrays have the same average. The output will not repeat the subarrays, but just the indices where they occur in the input array.

So for this input:

```
[
  [3, 3, 4, 2], // index 0: average = 3
  [4, 4],       // index 1: average = 4
  [4, 0, 3, 3], // index 2: average = 2.5
  [2, 3],       // index 3: average = 2.5
  [3, 3, 3],    // index 4: average = 3
];
```

The expected output is:

```
[[0, 4], [1], [2, 3]]
```

...because the subarrays at indices 0 and 4 have the same average, while the subarray at index 1 has an average that is not shared by another subarray, and finally the subarrays at indices 2 and 3 have the same average.

I completed the function as we see below, and the averages are calculated correctly, but I can't get the values of the object sorted with keys in distinct arrays...

```js
function solution(a) {
  let b = [];
  let entier = {};
  a.filter((elt, cle) => {
    let s = a[cle].reduce((prevalue, curvalue) => prevalue + curvalue, 0);
    b[cle] = s / a[cle].length;
    //console.log(s/a[cle].length)
    entier[cle] = s / a[cle].length;
  });
  console.log(entier);
  let arrNew = Object.entries(entier);
  console.log(arrNew);
}

let a = [
  [3, 3, 4, 2],
  [4, 4],
  [4, 0, 3, 3],
  [2, 3],
  [3, 3, 3],
];

solution(a); // [[0, 4], [1], [2, 3]]
```

How can I make my code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this:

```
entier[cle] = s / a[cle].length;
```

...you are assigning the average as a *value* associated with the current index as the *key*. But you need the opposite. You'll want to group by the average, so that must be the *key*, and the index must be the value (but as an array).

So change that to:

```
(entier["x" + (s / a[cle].length)] ??= []).push(cle);
```

The "x" is to ensure that the key is not an integer as then different rules apply for the ordering of that key in the object. By prepending this "x", we ensure that keys are ordered in the order they are created.

The `??=` assignment ensures that the property is initialised as an array when it didn't exist yet.

The second correction is here: `Object.entries` should be `Object.values` as you are no longer interested in those "x" keys.

```js
function solution(a) {
  let entier = {};
  a.filter((elt, cle) => {
    let s = a[cle].reduce((prevalue, curvalue) => prevalue + curvalue, 0);
    (entier["x" + (s / a[cle].length)] ??= []).push(cle);
  });
  let arrNew = Object.values(entier);
  console.log(arrNew);
}

let a = [
  [3, 3, 4, 2], // 0: 3
  [4, 4],       // 1: 4
  [4, 0, 3, 3], // 2: 2.5
  [2, 3],       // 3: 2.5
  [3, 3, 3],    // 4: 3
];

solution(a); // [[0, 4], [1], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the retrun ...
Could you please give me more informations and details about ??= assignment, because i never saw that in javascript ...

Comment: By a simple google it i found the ressource thank you https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment

Comment: For those that don't understand the  ??= assignment you can undestand clearly with that `(entier[s / a[cle].length]) ? entier[s / a[cle].length].push(cle) : entier[s / a[cle].length] = [cle];`